# How should I solve my login auth with two different users?

Tags: scala, authentication, profiles, mysql

In my project I have two seperate users. I have this table called userProfiles and the other one is called clientProfiles. They differ quite a lot but still has a couple of fields that are equal.

Both tables have the fields email and password. I'm going to use these for authentication but I don't want to create one request per user type.

I'm thinking of just making another table called allProfiles and put all user's and clients here.

ID | EMAIL | PASSWORD | TYPE

For this I'll have to put all existing user's into this table and also each time a new user/client is added it will be inserted here as well. Could this cause any problems?

I also thought about the option to create another object like:

```
object Profile {

  def getAllProfiles(){
    //return required fields for users & clients as a list
  }
}
```

and then use that list somehow for matching and authenticating.

I need some ideas or someone to tell me that this is wrong way of doing it. I've never done this with best practice methods before so I'm not very experienced and I want to do it the proper way this time.

I'm not sure if you have all the info you need, just tell me if so.

regads,

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong to do two queries to DB when you need it.

IMO you should never separate your data if you can solve your problem with two queries.

Also you may try to put all same fields in one table and the different ones in another. Like: `profile`, `user_profile` and `client_profile`.  But do not duplicate your data.